# Context and InitialContext - should I be calling the close() method on these objects?

Tags: java, servlets

Had I looked into the Java SE6 documentation sooner on Context and InitialContext, I would've seen that there is a `close()` method for each.

**So now I wonder, do I need to call the `close()` method on the Context/InitialContext objects?**

Here is a snippet of my typical servlet code and how the Context/InitialContext object is used.

```
public class MyTypicalServlet extends HttpServlet {     

    //thread safe
    DataSource ds;
    String FilePath;    

public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {

    super.init(config);
    try {
        final Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/myDB");

        FilePath = getServletContext().getInitParameter("FilePath");                

    } catch (NamingException e) {
        throw new ServletException("Unable to find datasource: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}               

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        doPost(req,res);
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException
    {       

    //...a bunch of code
    }

}//class
```

Comment: I do call `close()` but practically no impl. does anything since you can have subContexts and so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a good habit to get into. For example, I always make sure to close my InputStream classes, even if I'm using a ByteArrayInputStream, where the close() method is a no-op. That way, if I change it to some other implementation later, it's one less thing to have to change as well.

Same case here - if you call close(), you'll be more compatible with any JNDI implementation.

Answer (score 7):

The close method allows releasing resources used by the context instead of waiting for the GC to release them. It would perhaps be useful for a context needing an open connection to, for example, a database or an external system. But I'm pretty sure it isn't useful for the java:comp/env context. Anyway, I've never seen any code closing them.

Comment: Since I'm opening a connection to my database with the Context, should I use close() on the Context?...would it be of any benefit to me? I use quite a bit of memory as it is for my webapp, so I wonder if releasing the objects sooner vs. waiting for the GC to do it would be of use to me. What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: You're not opening a connection to your database with the context. You get access to a DataSource, which gives you access to a connection which you open. The connection doesn't know the context and has nothing to do with it. It is a good practice to close the context, but I wouldn't mind too much about it in this case.